# How to assign return from function

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to assign a value to end a loop, not sure how o if it's the right way of doing it.
Is it possible to assign the return value to a variable?

```
loop = True

def lose():
    print('Game Over')
    return False

def computer_end():
    if condition :   # resume 
       lose()

while loop:
    computer_end()
```

How can I assign the return False to the loop variable ?

Another way I thought

```
loop = True

def lose():
    print('Game Over')
    return False

def computer_end():
    if condition :   # resume 
       lose()


while loop:
    computer_end()
    if lose():  # if lose() has been used, break.
       break
```

Thanks

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to display the "Game over" message when the while loop is not valid anymore. Why not just print "Game over" after the while loop?

Comment: "Is it possible to assign the return value to a variable?" yes. of course it is. You do it the same way you assign *any* value to a variable, `x = y`, so say you have a function foo, then `x = foo()`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to avoid setting loop directly? If not, just add that inside your function.

```
loop = True

def lose():
    print('Game Over')
    loop = False
    return loop
```

Or, you could set it in the other function:

```
def computer_end():
    if condition :   # resume 
       loop = lose()
```

I don't think your second implementation would work the way you want it to. lose() always returns False and prints game over, so when running the if below 'Game Over' would be printed, and it would never break.

```
while loop:
    computer_end()
    if lose():  # if lose() has been used, break.
       break
```

Comment: You need the global keyword after the function declaration: `global loop`. Your last implementation is best though